# apt-get install in azure-pipelines fails randomly

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my `azure-pipelines.yaml` I have one script that install some dependencies.

```yaml
- script: |
    apt-get update
    apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
    apt-get install libgtk-3-0
  displayName: 'Dep install'
```

Sometimes it goes ok, sometimes it throw an error.

```
apt-get: command not found
```

Normally when I run again it goes ok. Did someone already get through that?

Comment: I changed `apt-get` to `apt` and put all the dependencies in one line like so: `apt install libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0` and I didn't get the error for now.

Comment: Please show your pipeline. You can skip additional steps, but leave stages/jobs etc.

Comment: Please refer to the following answer and check if it could work for you. If it doesn't work, you could share the agent you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to add `sudo` before the `apt-get`.

Password-less `sudo` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations).

> Run as an administrator on Windows and a passwordless sudo user on
> Linux

For example:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- script: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
    sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-0
  displayName: 'Dep install'
```

When I run the pipeline on linux Microsoft-hosted agent, it could work fine.

[image]

Comment: The first usage I did was with the `sudo`. The same error happened. I'm using the `ubuntu-latest` image too.

Comment: I was wrong! The company has an `pool` that in some cases uses CentOS.

Comment: @MathiasGhenoAzzolini.  Can you try to use the Hosted ubuntu agent (ubuntu-latest) and check if it could work? For centOS , are you using the self-hosted agent?

Comment: In order to make it work I needed to put one fixed agent in the `pool`. What I did understand is that the company has self-hosted and cloud hosted in the same `pool`. The cloud is ubuntu. Thank you for your support, I'll put your answer as the right one.